# Stripe Webhooks unable to hit DRF endpoint

Tags: django-rest-framework, stripe-payments, webhooks

I want to integrate stripe web-hook with an DRF application. So at first I install stripe CLI and then logged into stripe account using command `stripe login`.

Now, I wrote a simple APIView to handle POST from stripe. It does nothing but simply print what is sent by stripe -

```
class PaymentConfirmation(APIView):

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, booking, format=None):
        print(">>>>", request.data)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Then using following command I established connection between my endpoint and stripe -

```
stripe listen --events payment_intent.succeeded --format JSON --forward-to 127.0.0.1:8000/api/bookings/10/payment-confirmation/
```

This returned me -

```
Ready! You are using Stripe API Version [2020-08-27]. Your webhook signing secret is whsec******
```

Now when I try to hit the API view I wrote using this command -

```
stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded
```

I am seeing the success response -

```
Setting up fixture for: payment_intent
Running fixture for: payment_intent
Trigger succeeded! Check dashboard for event details.
```

The ***API*** is suppose to ***print*** the `request.data` on the terminal as per the ***print*** statement in the ***POST*** request but nothing is being printed. However, when I hit the same API via postman I see the it printing the `request.data`.

Where am I going wrong? What have I missed?

Comment: Can you try without --format flag? I don't see it listed on the reference doc so wondering if its supported with `listen` https://stripe.com/docs/cli/listen 

I'd also recommend adding `http://` before the IP to see if that changes anything

Comment: still the same, no luck

Comment: Are you seeing the request come in to your django server? what do you see if you try to print out just the request and not `request.data`?

Comment: It still doesn't work. However the endpoint is working just fine with postman